# Unpack WAR Is Not Unpacking

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to achieve the same objective to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529159/including-an-unpacked-war-in-the-assembly/27531848), namely to assemble a war dependency into a deployable zip, with both the war and some of its unpacked *.yml files in the final zip. I have the war file correctly assembled into the zip, but I can't get the maven-dependency-plugin to unpack the *.yml files out of the war for re-packing.

For clarity, this is what I have:

- Project 1

  - Name: myapp-war
  - Packaging: war
- Project 2

  - Name: myapp-deploy
  - Packaging: pom
  - Dependency: myapp-war:war
  - Desired output: myapp.zip which includes:

    - bin/myapp.war
    - conf/application-*.yml

Here's what my plugin declaration looks like:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>myapp</groupId>
                                <artifactId>myapp-war</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/unpack</outputDirectory>
                                <includes>**/*.yml</includes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I've also tried a variant where I declared the `<outputDirectory>` and `<includes>` just underneath the `<configuration>`, which is permissible per the [unpack mojo docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html).

In either case, I get an empty myapp-deploy/target/unpack folder, along with [INFO] and [DEBUG] messages in the maven output stating:

```
[INFO] Configured Artifact: myapp:myapp-war:?:war
[INFO] Unpacking /build/myapp-war/target/myapp-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /build/myapp-deploy/target/unpack with includes "**/*.yml" and excludes ""
[DEBUG] Found unArchiver by type: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipUnArchiver$__sisu2@692a65b1
[DEBUG] Expanding: /build/myapp-war/target/myapp-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war into /build/myapp-deploy/target/unpack
[DEBUG] expand complete
```

It appears that maven has understood my instructions, but doesn't seem to be unpacking as it claims to. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is apparently a problem with the creation of the *.war dependency. It is first created with `maven-war-plugin:war`, and then repackaged with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin:repackage`. Unzipping the war from the command line succeeds, but produces a warning:

```
$ unzip myapp-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
Archive:  myapp-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
warning [myapp-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]:  7318 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
```

If I configure `spring-boot-maven-plugin:repackage` to disable the prepending of an [executable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) *nix launch script to the war, `maven-dependency-plugin:unpack` works as expected:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>false</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```